# i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language vi failed failed parsing ../public/locales/vi/translation.json to json

Tags: javascript, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

**Problem**

loading namespace translation for language vi failed failed . . .

**What I did**

step 1: npx create-react-app AwesomeProject

step 2: `npm install i18next 18next-browser-languagedetector 18next-http-backend react-i18next`

step 3: I create "en" and "vi" folders in public/locales

The json file in **public/locales/en/translation.js** like this:

```
{
  "menuItem": {
    "dashboard__title": "Dashboard",
    "dashboard__subMenu": {},

    "task__title": "Task",
    "task__subMenu": {
      "task__child__1__title": "Internal mailbox",
      "task__child__1__subMenu": {},

      "task__child__2__title": "Calendar",
      "task__child__2__subMenu": {
        "task__child__2.1__title": "Work schedule management",
        "task__child__2.1__subMenu": {}
      },

      "task__child__3__title": "The job needs support",
      "task__child__3__subMenu": {},

      "task__child__4__title": "Notify",
      "task__child__4__subMenu": {
        "task__child__4.1__title": "View announcements",
        "task__child__4.1__subMenu": {},

        "task__child__4.2__title": "Manage notifications",
        "task__child__4.2__subMenu": {}
      }
    },

    "news__title": "News",
    "news__subMenu": {
      "news__child__1__title": "Calendar",
      "news__child__1__subMenu": {},

      "news__child__2__title": "Project management",
      "news__child__2__subMenu": {},

      "news__child__3__title": "Electronic vouchers",
      "news__child__3__subMenu": {}
    },

    "humanResource__title": "Human Resource",
    "humanResource__subMenu": {},

    "cms__title": "CMS",
    "cms__subMenu": {},

    "calendar__title": "Calendar",
    "calendar__subMenu": {},

    "docs__title": "Documentation",
    "docs__subMenu": {},

    "elearning__title": "Elearning",
    "elearning__subMenu": {},

    "category__title": "Category",
    "category__subMenu": {},

    "system__title": "System",
    "system__subMenu": {},

    "feedback__title": "Feedback",
    "feedback__subMenu": {},

    "users__title": "User",
    "users__subMenu": {},

    "folder__title": "Folder",
    "folder__subMenu": {},

    "androi__title": "Androi",
    "androi__subMenu": {},

    "ios__title": "Ios",
    "ios__subMenu": {}
  }
}
```

step 4: I create i18n.js file byside index.js file like this:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import LangugeDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend'

i18n
  .use(LangugeDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'vi'],
    lng: 'vi',
    fallbackLng: 'vi',
    detection: {
      order: ['cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'path', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie']
    },

    backend: {
      loadPath: '../public/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json'
    },

    debug: true
  })

export default i18n
```

step 5: import i18n.js in index.js file

```
i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language vi failed failed parsing ../public/locales/vi/translation.json to json

i18next: languageChanged vi
i18next.js:27 i18next: initialized {debug: true, initImmediate: true, ns: Array(1), defaultNS: Array(1), fallbackLng: Array(1), …}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste your vi/translation.json in here https://jsonlint.com/ and validate it to see if it is a correct json

Also check the network request in the developer console… it might be the path is not correct…

Comment: hi @adrai,
the results:
=> Valid JSON

Comment: check your network request in the developer console

Comment: Hi @adrai, the network request:
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/public/locales/vi/translation.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin